# How to get OpenVino toolkit to work with Anaconda Environment on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda, intel, openvino

I am trying to get the Intel OpenVino toolkit to work on an Anaconda environment. I know Anaconda has a package to get the Openvino tool kit. However, I have already installed the pre-requisite installation for Windows 10. How do I go about setting up the Openvino toolkit to work with the already existing Anaconda Environment?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to get the pre-requisite in your system first:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio* with C++ 2019 or 2017 with MSBuild ( I recommend 2019)
2. CMake 2.8.12 or higher 64-bit (ensure that this added to your system's path)
3. Python 3.5 - 3.7 64-bit ( I recommend 3.6)
4. Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ toolkit core components (2020.4 is the latest)

Since you already done that, you can proceed to next steps.

create a virtual env : conda create --name

conda activate

(then proceed the next steps of installation here, as in official Openvino documentation provided below)

conda cheat sheet: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-chea...

This is Openvino official documentation that shows step by step installation process: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.htm...